# Validation in DTO not working in api-platform 3.2

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com, symfony6

We have a api endpoint like

```
#[MapRequestPayload(acceptFormat: 'json', resolver: CustomValueResolver::class)] ExampleDTO $data
```

And resolver is supposed to send 422 response with violations

```
final class CustomValueResolver implements ValueResolverInterface, EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private DefaultRequestPayloadValueResolver $defaultResolver;

    public function __construct(
        SerializerInterface&DenormalizerInterface $serializer,
        ?ValidatorInterface $validator = null,
        ?TranslatorInterface $translator = null,
    ) {
        $this->defaultResolver = new DefaultRequestPayloadValueResolver($serializer, $validator, $translator);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER_ARGUMENTS => 'onKernelControllerArguments',
        ];
    }

    public function resolve(Request $request, ArgumentMetadata $argument): iterable
    {
        return $this->defaultResolver->resolve($request, $argument);
    }

    public function onKernelControllerArguments(ControllerArgumentsEvent $event): void
    {
        try {
            $this->defaultResolver->onKernelControllerArguments($event);
        } catch (HttpException $e) {
            $previous = $e->getPrevious();
            if ($previous instanceof ValidationFailedException) {
                throw new ValidationException($previous->getViolations());
            }

            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

But after updating to api-platform 3.2 we are getting 500 errors with the trace of the exception

Anything that might go wrong?

Comment: Could you please share us the trace of the exception message? I encountered a similar problem, because my other denormalizers wasn't excluding some types. I updated the function getSupportedTypes(?string $format) to exclude other types.